# Trouble with calculating net pay using hours worked, hourly rate, and functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, payment

Typical salary exercise to solve net pay using only hourly rate and worked hours but this time gotta apply ALL functions down below and in overtime, the pay will be double after 40 hours, the taxes are 10% and the benefits are: health care = $50, social security = 6%, retirement = 3%

[The code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ndGN.png)

Comment: And what is the problem?  Does it work?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Your functions need to RETURN the values they compute, and the functions that call them need to store the results for future use.

Comment: @bhruhgehrs. Please post the code as a text, not a screenshot.

Comment: please provide code as text, not as image